# PHP MYSQL insert category tree

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Sorry for my english.
I've got table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `export_raw_categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL ,
  `parent_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `parent_category_name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL ,
  `profile_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

And I've got an array in PHP:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => AFirst
        [1] => ASecond
        [2] => AThird
        [3] => AFourth
        [4] => AFifth
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => BFirst
        [1] => BSecond
        [2] => BThird
        [3] => BFourth
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => BFirst
        [1] => BSixth
    )

)
```

For example:

Array with key 0 is categoty tree like: `AFirst\ASecond\AThird\AFourth\AFifth`

So AFirst is the root category with `parent_category_name` as NULL

`ASecond` is category with `parent_category_name` `AFirst`

`AThird` is category with `parent_category_name` `ASecond`

And so on.

My question is how to assign proper `parent_category_id` in database?

---

Here is my code in `PHP` (Codeigniter) but that don't give me good results:

```
foreach ($d as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val as $sub_key => $sub_val) {

            $root_cat = array(
                'profile_name' => 'XYZ',
                'category_name' => $val[0],
                'parent_category_name' => null,
                'root_category' => null
            );

            $query = $this->db->get_where('export_raw_categories', $root_cat);
            if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
                $this->db->insert('export_raw_categories', $root_cat);
                $root_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            } else if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
                $root_id = $query->row('category_id');
            }

            if (isset($val[$sub_key - 1])) {

                $category_name = $sub_val;
                $parent_category_name = $val[$sub_key - 1];
                $root_cat = $val[0];

                $category = array(
                    'profile_name' => 'XYZ',
                    'category_name' => $sub_val,
                    'parent_category_name' => $parent_category_name,
                    'parent_category_id' => $root_id,
                    'root_category' => $parent_category_name . "\\" . $category_name
                );


                $query = $this->db->get_where('export_raw_categories', $category);
                if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
                    $this->db->insert('export_raw_categories', $category);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

This works:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $categories) {
        $parent = NULL;
        foreach ($categories as $key_cat => $cat) {

            $category = array(
                'profile_name' => 'XYZ',
                'category_name' => $cat,
                'parent_category_name' => isset($categories[$key_cat - 1]) ? $categories[$key_cat - 1] : null,
                'parent_category_id' => $parent
                // 'root_category' => $parent_category_name . "\\" . $category_name
            );

            $query = $this->db->get_where('export_raw_categories', $category);
            if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
                $this->db->insert('export_raw_categories', $category);
                $parent = $this->db->insert_id();
            } else if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
                $parent = $query->row('category_id');
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to @Rok D. for input in right direction.
So should I now upvote Your answer or accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this (just showing the logic not the exact syntax since you can obviously write your own SQL queries.

```
foreach ($arr as $categories) {
    $existingRoot = $this->db->query(); // SELECT category_id... WHERE category_name = $categories[0] 
    // If only roots can appear as 1st item then add AND parent_category_id = 0 
    $parent = $existingRoot ? $existingRoot->category_id : 0;
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if ($cat == $existingRoot->category_name) {
            continue;
        }
        $this->db->insert();
        $parent = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thank You - it's closer but when categories are the same it's wrong, see pic:  [link](https://ibb.co/k5WBkJ)

Comment: Updated so it won't duplicate categories

Comment: hi, Thank You, I've made it almost identical to your answer. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Great you've managed to solve it. You can do any of them or both, whatever you feel is best :)

Answer (score 0):

i'd split this in 2 functions - one iterates over the base array - the other is responsible for the data handling.

Something like that should work

```
public function tree()
{
    $d = [
        [
            'AFirst', 'ASecond', 'AThird', 'AFourth', 'AFifth'
        ],
        [
            'BFirst', 'BSecond',  'BThird', 'BFourth'
        ],
        [
            'BFirst', 'BSixth'
        ]
    ];
    foreach($d AS $arrData)
    {
        $this->insert($arrData);
    }
}

function insert($arrData, $arrParentData = null)
{

    if (is_array($arrData) && count($arrData) > 0)
    {
        $strData = array_shift($arrData);

        $arrDbData = [
            'category_name' => $strData,
        ];

        if ($arrParentData)
        {
            $arrDbData = array_merge($arrDbData, $arrParentData);
        }
        $this->db->insert('export_raw_categories', $arrDbData);
        $parentId = $this->db->insert_id();

        $arrParentData = [
            'parent_category_name' => $strData,
            'parent_category_id' => $parentId
        ];

        $this->insert($arrData, $arrParentData);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for response, First - in function tree() it will duplicate categorye BFirst, Second - if any sub category will have the same name in any array it will get confused to what category assign parent_category_id

Comment: it doesnt matter how you call your category - there is an unique id - so i dont understand what you mean...